# ping localhosts, edit /etc/network/hosts

Tags: networking, localhost, ping, hostname, hosts

I want to succesfully **ping some hostnames**. These **hostnames have the same IP, 127.0.0.1**

So i edited **/etc/network/hosts**:

```
127.0.0.1 host1 
127.0.0.1 host2 
127.0.0.1 host3
127.0.0.1 host4
127.0.0.1 host5 
127.0.0.1 host6
127.0.0.1 host7 
127.0.0.1 host8 
127.0.0.1 host9
```

My **/etc/network/interfaces** file was:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Then i added this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
 address 127.0.0.1
 network 127.0.0.0
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 broadcast 127.0.0.255
```

But when i try to do:

```
ping host1
```

***it doesn't work***, even with other hostnames in /etc/network/hosts

Comment: I'm curious why someone has downvoted this, instead of replying me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the recent kernels the couples hostname-IP are **saved in /etc/hosts**, not in /etc/network/hosts, the edit in /etc/network/interfaces is useless, i just tried everything